# How to connect to WiFi with nmcli

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, nmcli

I am a new Linux user (windows before), and I downloaded Arch Linux last night.

The installation was fairly straightforward, but after I rebooted I no longer had connection to WiFi. Thankfully I had downloaded `networkmanager`, however I still can't seem to connect to the internet.

For one when I use the command

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

nothing happens. I added a connection directly to my IP address which worked, however it didn't become an active connection. I know if I reinstall arch I can get a different network manager, but I would rather not.

How can I connect to my network?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to indicate what WiFi adapter you are using.

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
nmcli radio wifi
```

If the output shows that the Wi-Fi is disabled, you can enable it with the following command:

```
nmcli radio wifi on
```

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

To list the available Wi-Fi Access Point

With Wi-Fi enabled and your SSID identified, you're now ready to connect. You can establish a connection with the following command:

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi connect network-ssid-name
```

Replace network-ssid-name with the name of your network. If you have WEP or WPA security on your WI-Fi, you can specify the network password in the command as well.

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi connect network-ssid password "network-password"
```